# S3 endpoint access denied error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have added a public access policy on my S3 bucket. Inside the property of the object in S3 bucket the url is 
http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/{bucketname}/{objectKey}

I am using following code to get the service endpoint using`RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("RegionName").GetEndpointForService("S3")`
so I can generate the link programmatically but it gives me 's3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com' as a result.

Why it is not giving me 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com' (see the hyphen after s3) ?

Comment: Are you actually using "RegionName" in your call to `GetBySystemName`?

Comment: Which SDK are you using? What version?

Comment: I am using 'us-west-2' in Region Name. I am using the latest version of the SDK

Comment: What SDK language? Java? .NET? What is the version number of your SDK?

Comment: @MattHouser the answer to those questions may reveal something interesting. I suspect S3 is planning to start allowing the region endpoints for the older regions to also match the usual convention of service.region.amazonaws.com -- some newer regions accept the new style dot or the old style dash but not  us-west-2 -- its TLS cert now supports both (even `*.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` now appears in the SAN, which is new), but S3 misinterprets the `Host:` header if you actually address us-west-2 that way, and it's not yet a documented endpoint. If it's a really new SDK version, then... "oops."

Comment: Interesting. The latest AWS SDK for .NET gives `s3-us-west-2` as the endpoint for `us-west-2`. However, for "unknown" regions, it will return `s3.<whateveryouinput>`. The Github repo for the Java SDK also shows `s3-us-west-2` as the endpoint. Based on the syntax in the question, I would have thought the OP was using .NET or Java. So I'm really curious what SDK the OP is using.

Comment: @MattHouser I am using .Net SDK. When you call `RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("us-west-2")` you will get us-west-2 as SystemName but when you try to get the Endpoint for S3 then it returns `S3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`

Comment: @MattHouser - GetEndpointForService is caseSensitive with the inputs. 
`RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("RegionName").GetEndpointForService("S3")` yields `S3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`
where `RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("RegionName").GetEndpointForService("s3")` yields `s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Aha. So it was case-sensitivity on the service name. Good to know.

Comment: Interesting.  Consider posting that as an answer to your own question for the benefit of others.  When you really do solve it yourself, that's totally [allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).  Note, for the record, that my speculation was based on other external observations of apparent trends, and I still expect S3 to eventually normalize all of its endpoints, without removing and probably without even officially deprecating, the old ones.  It's good to know, though, that this issue is unrelated.  Such a lapse would have been out-of-character for AWS.

Answer (score 0):

RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("RegionName").GetEndpointForS‌​ervice("S3") yields S3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com where RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("RegionName").GetEndpointForS‌​ervice("s3") yields s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com